# Is Maximum Likelihood Estimation the median?

Tags: r, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, inference, actuarial-science

I asked what maximum likelihood estimation to a friend of mine. He told me that it is the median which I don't understand.

Comment: Even though I can't comprehend the question, your friend's answer is wrong in general. For many distributions, though, the MLE is the mean and for symmetric distributions the distributional mean is the distributional median (though sample mean/median differ). The sample median is the MLE for a double exponential distribution.

Comment: You can almost treat it literally. If a function is a likelihood or density function - density is more intuitive - then maximum likelihood estimation is the process of estimating the value of the function with the highest density.

Comment: I'd suggest beginning by reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation - it may help you to formulate a clearer question

Answer (score 5):

No - MLE is closer in concept to the mode of the likelihood

In a Bayesian sense starting with a flat prior, the posterior distribution would be proportional to the likelihood.  The Maximum Likelihood Estimate would then correspond to the mode of the posterior distribution.  If you had a squared distance loss function, the optimal choice for a point estimate would instead be the mean of the posterior distribution, while with an absolute difference loss function the optimal choice would be the median of the posterior distribution

In general, there is no particular reason why the mode, median and mean of a distribution should be the same, unless you believe the distribution is symmetric and unimodal